# ¿Cómo imprimir 1 pdf por registro de un informe access concatenando varios campos de la base de datos para nombrarlo?

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

Es mi primera consulta en este foro y, la verdad, mis conocimientos de programación VBA son nulos.

Os expongo mi problema:

- Tengo una base de datos con varios registros en access.
- Cada registro, que corresponde a un producto, tiene 43 campos:

  - un campo "Código",
  - un campo "Denominacion",
  - otro campo "Peso"
  - y otro campo "versión".

Lo que intento conseguir es imprimir 1 informe en pdf por cada registro de la base de datos de forma que el nombre que tenga cada pdf sea una concatenación de los campos "Denominación"+"peso"+"versión" de la base de datos para cada registro.

Tengo la base de datos, un formulario y un informe con todos los registros de la base de datos.

- El nombre del formulario y del informe es el mismo, "empresa".
- La ruta, "C:\Users\Pepito\Documents\FTPS\"

El código más parecido que he podido encontrar el el siguiente:

*(Lo he sacado de este mismo [foro en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296884/how-can-i-output-a-report-in-pdf-format-where-the-name-consists-of-values-from) y lo he adaptado a mis datos):*

```
Private Sub Create_PDF_Click()

Dim myPath As String
Dim strReportName As String

DoCmd.OpenReport "Empresa", acViewPreview

myPath = "C:\Users\Pepito\Documents\FTPS\" 

strReportName = "FTP cód" + Report_Empresa.[CODIGO] + "_" +
Report_empresa.[DENOMINACION] + "_" + Report_empresa.[PESO]  + "g Rev." + Report_Empresa.[VERSION] + ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Invoices"
```

Pero al hacer funcionar la macro me da un error de sintaxis en el nombre. Creo que no estoy citando bien los campos de la base de datos, pese a que he puesto entre corchetes los mismos nombres que tengo en los campos de mi base de datos.

Por otra parte, no sé si esto bastaría para que me imprimiera en PDF's separados todos los registros de la base de datos, con sus nombres correspondientes, o si debería añadir alguna instrucción más.

Si pudierais orientarme un poco, os lo agradecería enormemente.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Probaste a concatenar con `&`?

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido,
Intenta simplificando el nombre que le estás dando, evita tildes y simbolos de ser posible.

```
strReportName = "FTP cod" + Report_Empresa.[CODIGO] + "_" +
Report_empresa.[DENOMINACION] + "_" + Report_empresa.[PESO]  + "g Rev" + Report_Empresa.[VERSION] + ".pdf"
```